# Limit in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to 0} x \ln (xy) ?$
Problem for this problem is already solved here on MSE. 
But can't we find the limit using polar coordinates.

As $\lim _{r \to 0} r \cos \theta \ln( r^{2} \cos \theta \sin \theta) = 0$ so limit should be zero.

But the limit of this function doesn't exist.
What is wrong with this method$?$

Comment: You assume implicitly that $\theta$ is constant if you say that the limit is $0$.

Comment: But this limit is defined for all $\theta$, when $\theta$ varies with the variation in $r$, still the limit goes to zero.

Comment: @Mathsaddict That's not true: it doesn't for $\;\theta=\begin{cases}\frac\pi2\\\pi\end{cases}+2k\pi,\,k\in\Bbb Z$

Comment: But $\theta$ may change as $r\to 0$. And you have no control over how; the limit should exist no matter how $\theta$ changes.

Comment: When you take the limit as $r \to 0$, you assume that $\theta$ is a fixed constant, i. e., you are only considering straight lines to the origin. So what you would have to show is that the limit is equal to $0$ no matter what path you choose for going to $(0, 0)$.

Comment: I think to prove the existence of limit, I should show that the limit of function is bounded by some function of $r$ which doesn't depend on theta and this function of $r$ should tend to a finite value.

Comment: @Mathsaddict That's right. But you can't do that for this function, as for any $r$, choosing a $\theta$ close to any multiple of a quarter rotation gives arbitrarily large (as in far away from zero) negative values. So there is no independent-of-$\theta$ bound.

Comment: (I meant a multiples of a half rotation. Sorry.)

Comment: Note that the function $x\ln(xy)$ is not even defined when $x=0$ or $y=0$. For most (all?) multivariable calculus courses, to talk about the limit, the function needs to be defined on a punctured neighborhood of the point you're approaching, i.e., in this case on some set $0<x^2+y^2<\delta$. This function is not.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Not all courses! Where I teach, we only require that the point is an accumulation point of the domain of $f$.

Comment: @HansLundmark, Sure, in Europe calculus courses are all analysis courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $t \in A:= \Bbb{R}\setminus\{2k\pi,2k\pi +\pi/2:k \in Z\}$

$x\log(xy)=x\log{x} +x\log{y}$ thus for $x=r\cos{t}$ and $y=r \sin{t}$

we have that $f(r,t) \to 0$ as $r \to 0$ using the fact  that $r\log{r} \to 0$ as $r \to 0$

Since $t$ is arbitrary in $A$ we conclude that the limit exists.

Comment: For $\theta=0$, the function is undefined, so those points are not to be taken into accunt when computing the limit. (But you can look *close* to those points, of course.)

Comment: The edited answer is also wrong, since the limit in fact does **not** exist... You can't assume $t$ to be constant as you let $r \to 0$. Have you tried plotting the function?